# Initialize ViewModelFactory

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, android-architecture-components

From my understanding, the ViewModelFactory class is mandatory if your ViewModel class has parameters in its constructor. How then can I initialize my ViewModelFactory class in my activity apart from using Dependency Injection? Below is my Factory class

```
public class ViewModelFactory  implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {
private final Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators;


public ViewModelFactory(Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators) {
    this.creators = creators;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
    Provider<? extends ViewModel> creator = creators.get(modelClass);
    if (creator == null) {
        for (Map.Entry<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> entry : creators.entrySet()) {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(entry.getKey())) {
                creator = entry.getValue();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (creator == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class " + modelClass);
    }
    try {
        return (T) creator.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  } 
}
```

And here is my activity class

```
public class RestaurantListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LifecycleRegistryOwner {

private LifecycleRegistry lifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_restaurant_list);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //How do I initialize this?
    ViewModelFactory mViewModelFactory;

    MyViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,mViewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel.class);
    viewModel.init();

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that this way:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    ViewModelProvider.Factory factory = new ViewModelProvider.Factory() {
        @Override
        public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
            if (modelClass.equals(SomeObject.class)) {
                // instantiate `someObject`
                return someObject;
            } else if (modelClass.equals(SomeOtherObject.class)) {
                // instantiate `someOtherObject`
                return someOtherObject;
            } else {
                return ...;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP asks about how to initialize it, and you provide code to define it...

Comment: @mohkamfer, I believe `new ViewModelProvider.Factory()` is called initialization. Not sure what you mean by _"define"_.

Comment: Can we have a generic ViewModelFactory class for all the ViewModels  that are present in my app ? And Can i make the ViewModelFactory class a singleton ?